# Cannot remove whitespace in Pandas data frame with Excel Import

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame with employee name and charging information, by month.  This is read in from an Excel File in Pandas.  When doing the read, the names aren't left justified and I believe I have whitespace.  It prevents me from filtering as I can't simply filter on 'Full Name'.  I tried using df['Full Name'].str.strip() but the spaces remain.  Any suggestions on removing the spaces?  When I look at a particular value, e.g.:

`df['Full Name'].iloc[3]` I don't see the spaces:

Below is a redacted and small sample of the df.

```
      Full Name                   08-Jan-23  15-Jan-23  22-Jan-23  29-Jan-23  ...  26-Feb-23  05-Mar-23  12-Mar-23  19-Mar-23  26-Mar-23  02-Apr-23
0   Smith, Robert MiddleName       0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000  ...     0.6650     0.6125     0.6425      0.665     0.6650     0.6650
1   Doe, Jane Leslie Aimee         0.0000     0.0000    -0.0550     0.0000  ...     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000      0.000     0.0000     0.0000
2          Baker, SomeGuy          0.0500     0.0000     0.0250     0.0875  ...     0.0125     0.0000     0.0000      0.000     0.0000     0.0000
3          Johsnon, AGuy           0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0325  ...     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000      0.000     0.0000     0.0250
```

Comment: What is the output of of `df['Full Name'].head().to_dict()`?

Comment: ```0: 'Smith, Robert Middlename'
   1: 'Doe, Jane Leslie Aimee'
   2: 'Baker, SomeGuy  '
   3: 'Johnson, AGuy  '```

Comment: Did you use `df['Full Name'] = df['Full Name'].str.strip()`?

Comment: Yessir I did but then realized that removes the other columns and only keeps Full Name.

Comment: No that doesn't.

Comment: ah.. my bad.  I was lazy and just assigned it to a new 'test' df. You're right, assigning it to the same dF does not strip and the trailing whitespace is gone.. thanks!